# WPF validation order between IDataErrorInfo and exception

Tags: wpf, validation, exception, binding, idataerrorinfo

I have a control that has both `ValidatesOnDataErrors = true` and `ValidatesOnExceptions = true`.  I also have something watching the `Validation.Errors` collection for this binding.

The user enters a value that's convertible (no exception) but invalid (IDataErrorInfo reports an error message).  The error appears in the errors collection, and is displayed as expected.

The user then enters a value that's not convertible (exception thrown).  The IDataErrorInfo still reports the same error as before (since the model value didn't change).

In this latter case, I would prefer to see the exception error alone in the list, but would accept having both the exception and the data error (in any order).

However, what's actually happening is that only the data error ends up in the list, which ends up giving the user a misleading error message (since it's the error for the previous value they entered, not the current one).

Tracing it through internally, it appears that when the second user action occurs, the exception error is added to the list, then removed again and replaced with the data error.  At no time do both errors appear in the list at the same time.

Any ideas how to get the desired behaviour out of this?

(Pulling back a step: what I'm trying to achieve is combining IDataErrorInfo validation [since it's more convenient for domain-level tests], but still paying attention to UI exceptions [otherwise it'd ignore the case when the user types in something totally silly].  I don't want to go to the extreme of making every VM property a string or other such nonsense.)

Answer (score 0):

The [ValidatesOnDataError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.validatesondataerrors.aspx) and [ValidatesOnExceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.validatesonexceptions.aspx) are simply helper properties that add instances of [DataErrorValidationRule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.dataerrorvalidationrule.aspx) and [ExceptionValidationRule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.exceptionvalidationrule.aspx) to the [ValidationRules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.validationrules.aspx) collection, respectively.

So you may be able to make the ExceptionValidationRule take precedence by explicitly defining the order like so:

```
<Binding Path="StartPrice" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
    <Binding.ValidationRules>
        <ExceptionValidationRule />
        <DataErrorValidationRule />
    </Binding.ValidationRules>
</Binding>
```

Comment: I haven't tried this specifically yet, but even if this works it would still result in only one of the two "winning", since it seems to clear the errors collection between each rule (for some inexplicable reason).

(And I suspect that the order you have them above is actually the order they're currently executing in.  I would have to list the Exception rule *last* if I wanted it to "win".)

Comment: I believe the validation process stops on the first rule that fails (i.e. declares the data invalid). So if you want the ExceptionValidationRule to win, it would need to go first. You can verify this by looking in BindingExpressionBase.Validate(Object, ValidationStep) in Reflector.